# Concatenate array of arrays

Tags: julia

I have an array of arrays in Julia and am trying to find a way to concatenate all of the elements together.  If I create the arrays and feed them each individually into `hcat()`, it performs exactly as I would want.  But, if I create the arrays and then feed the array of arrays into `hcat()`, it fails.  I could just write a loop to successfully concatenate one array to another, but I am wondering if there is a better way.

```
a = ones(2,2);
b = ones(2,2);
c = ones(2,2);    

hcat(a,b,c) ## Does what I want by creating a single array.  would be impracticable though for large number of objects.  

d = Array(Array{Float64,2}, 3);
d[1] = a;
d[2] = b;
d[3] = c;    

hcat(d) ## Still leaves me with an array of arrays, like before    

[a b c]  ## also does what I want
[f for f in d]  ## Still leaves me with an array of arrays
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
julia> hcat(d)
3x1 Array{Array{Float64,2},2}:
 2x2 Array{Float64,2}:
 1.0  1.0
 1.0  1.0
 2x2 Array{Float64,2}:
 1.0  1.0
 1.0  1.0
 2x2 Array{Float64,2}:
 1.0  1.0
 1.0  1.0

julia> hcat(d...)
2x6 Array{Float64,2}:
 1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
 1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
```